# Like newid() in SQL Server 208, for Teradata?

Tags: teradata

For each and every new table creation in Teradata, Is there any pseudo column is creating with unique values by default??

Kindly help me sir, I have tried all the possible ways to achieve my task, I think, this is the last option!

In SQL SERVER 2008, select newid() from table_name; gives unique column values. 
Like that, Are we having like this option in Teradata?

please guide me sir!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [i am migrtaing database from sql server 2008 to teradata](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17856834/i-am-migrtaing-database-from-sql-server-2008-to-teradata)

Comment: Again: For a new table there's GENERATED ALWAYS AS IDENTITY. Of course, you can ask over and over again. Or implement a C-UDF returning a GUID.

Comment: @dnoeth Yes, I understand your concern. But I've no idea of creating new table. I understand, if I have creating new table, I will user GENERATED ALWAYS AS IDENTITY.  What about the existing tables?  How can I find the pseudo column for each and every existing tables in Teradata? Is there any concept of having pseudo column for each and every tables by default, in TERADATA?

Comment: In a DWH you usually don't add some meaningless column like IDENTITY or GUID to each and every table, this is normally part of the ETL process. How does your ETL allow loading duplicate rows? What do you think you get when you simply add it to an existing table, a PK?

Comment: I think you got misunderstood, Let it be clear, I need a unique column in each and every Teradata table for validation, like sql server using select newid() from table_name , returns unique values for each row, same like that in Teradata, how can I achieve?? Or its Not POSSIBLE ?

Comment: *Validation* of what? Implement a C-UDF returning a GUID.